# building an anchor with js

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to build the following HTML using JavaScript:

```
<td> <a data-toggle="modal" class="btn" href="sales.asp?origen=NY&number=036529" data-target="#myModal">View Sale</a> </td>
```

I'm trying to build it using the following code, but I get errors:

```
document.write("<td> <a data-toggle='modal' class='btn' href=.......
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

my  script is this one, whre I want to add a button to open a modal window showing a page which has a parameter taken from the "for"

```
<script>
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
  xmlhttp.open("GET","xml/xml_compras.asp?origen=granada",false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 


 document.write("<table class='table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered' id='example'>");
document.write("<thead>");
  document.write("<tr class='odd gradeX'>");
  document.write("<th>Albaran</th>");
    document.write("<th>Proveedor</th>");
    document.write("<th>F. Albaran</th>");
    document.write("<th>F. Servicio</th>");
    document.write("<th>Articulo</th>");
    document.write("<th>Cantidad</th>");
    document.write("<th class='hidden-phone'>Precio</th>");
    document.write("<th class='hidden-phone'>Importe</th>");
    document.write("<th>Alb. Venta</th>");
 document.write("</tr>");
 document.write(" </thead>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");

for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
document.write("<tr>");
document.write("<td>");  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("numeroAlbaran")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);  document.write("</td>");
document.write("<td>");  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("proveedor")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);  document.write("</td>");
document.write("<td>");  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("fechaAlbaran")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);  document.write("</td>");
document.write("<td>");  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("fechaServicio")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);  document.write("</td>");
document.write("<td>");  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("articulo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);  document.write("</td>");
document.write("<td>");  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("cantidad")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);  document.write("</td>");
document.write("<td class='hidden-phone'>");     document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("precio")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);      document.write("</td>");
 document.write("<td class='hidden-phone'>");    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("importe")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);    document.write("</td>");
 document.write("<td>");  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("albaranVenta")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);  document.write("</td>");
var url = document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("importe")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
 //alert(url);
 document.write("<td> <a data-toggle='modal' class='btn' href="'+url+'"> data-target='#myModal'>click me</a> </td>")


document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

Comment: can't use document.write for that. See here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml

Comment: It looks like you want to work with DOM (mb i'm wrong). If you're not realy good in straight JS, you should consider using jQuery for DOM.

Comment: First thing u cant use document.write it will replace all your page with whatever you have written in it. second if possible provide full code of whatever you are trying to achieve to get the quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use vanilla JavaScript with DOM API:

```js
// creating the desired elements
var td = document.createElement('td');
var a = document.createElement('a');

// applying attributes
a.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');
a.setAttribute('data-target', '#myModal');
a.setAttribute('class', 'btn');
a.setAttribute('href', 'sales.asp?origen=NY&number=036529');

// textContent is preferred to innerHTML of innerText due consistency issues
a.textContent = 'View Sale';

// injecting the anchor into the table cell
td.appendChild(a);

// placing all of this into the DOM
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(td);
```

---

[<sub>[image: jsfiddle-icon]</sub> **Demo on jsFiddle**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcOfc.png)

Comment: I agree, jQuery isn't for everything. But your solution is like 9 lines long, compared to my 1. The size of your code is about 1/60th the size of all of jQuery. That said, it does work.

Comment: i'm not dissing jQuery, it's a *great* library. it's just that the OP did not mention using it, so i'm reluctant of pushing it where it's not needed.

Comment: I agree with @EliranMalka. The solution here may be nine lines long but including jQuery means a much longer solution -- it's just that the extra lines are hidden in another file, written by someone else. JQuery *is* great but if someone isn't using jQuery, or doesn't mention using it, asking them to add it into their script to solve one problem isn't particularly efficient.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can create a link to google and append it to the element with the id "content" as follows:

```
 $("<a/>",{"href":"http://www.google.com"}).text("Google").appendTo("#content");
```

JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/AstFZ/

Answer (score 0):

As others have said `document.write()` will overwrite the rest of your page. More importantly, even if it did work, how would it know where to put your table cell?

Instead:

1. Create the element on the document.

   ```
   var td = document.createElement('td');
   ```
2. It's not yet added to the DOM properly but that's okay. Next we need to create the content, i.e. the link that goes inside the cell. You can do this in a similar way to the `<td>` but it's more efficient, both in terms of writing and in terms of code performance, to add this to the `innerHTML` property of `td`. Like so:

   ```
   td.innerHTML = '<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn" href="sales.asp?origen=NY&number=036529" data-target="#myModal">View Sale</a>'
   ```
3. Lastly, add `td` to the place in the document where you want it to appear.

   ```
   // `table` should be the table you want to add the cell to
   // for example, if your table has the id 'table'...
   var table = document.getElementById('table'); // will get table

   table.appendChild(td); // will append `td`, your cell and link to the table
   ```

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct way I want, so I create the table and insert a button with a link wich is composed with an element of an array:

```
 <script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
  else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","xml/xmlBuys.asp?origen=NY",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 


document.write("<table class='table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered' id='example'>");
document.write("<thead>");
  document.write("<tr class='odd gradeX'>");

    document.write("<th>Button</th>");
 document.write("</tr>");
 document.write(" </thead>");
 var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");

 for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
 { 
 document.write("<tr>");



 document.write("<td> <a data-toggle='modal' class='btn' href='sales.asp?origen=NY&number="); document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("numSale")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); document.write("' data-target='#myModal'>  View Sale  </a> ");                document.write("</td>");



 document.write("</tr>");
 }
document.write("</table>");  
</script>
```